# UILocationNotfication.fireDate in the past - bug?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

According to [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on `UILocationNotification.fireDate`:

> If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the
>   notification is delivered immediately.

I am not seeing this behavior when using a date in the past.  Is it just me, or are others seeing this as well?

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *notifications = [NSMutableArray array];
UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
alarm.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time(NULL)-5];
alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
alarm.soundName = @"alarm.caf";
alarm.alertBody = @"Test";
alarm.alertAction = @"Launch";
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userInfo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"PsID"];
alarm.userInfo = userInfo;
notifications = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;
```

If I change the time(NULL)-5 to time(NULL)+5 I get the notification 5 seconds after this code runs.  With the -5 value, I never get the notification.

I know good questions here need to have a possible definite answer and this could be subject to a lot of "me too" answers -- **so what I'm looking for is something official (quote/link) from Apple saying this is expected behavior, or different version of the above code that works as the docs say it should.**

This is important for my application because in some cases I need to notify the user of an alarm even if it happened earlier in the day.  I suppose I could modify my code to check the current time and always give a value a few seconds beyond that -- but I'm not sure "how many seconds beyond" is really safe, and I would like it to happen ASAP -- also rather not have that hack if there is a better way to get "documented behavior".  My real code is similar to above, but I am posting several notifications, some might be in the past, some later today, some tomorrow and beyond (this is for a calendar application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@eselk,

I see the same behavior as you: a newly-created `UILocalNotification` that has a **fireDate** in the past will NOT fire ***if it is installed by setting the `scheduledLocalNotifications` property*** on the UIApplication object.

However, if the same `UILocalNotification` object is installed using UIApplication's `scheduleLocalNotification` method, it ***will*** fire immediately.

Seems to me to be a bug based on [the documentation for scheduledLocalNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which states pretty clearly that:

> ...When you set [the scheduledLocalNotifications] property, UILocalNotification
>   replaces all existing notifications by calling
>   cancelLocalNotification: and then calling scheduleLocalNotification:
>   for each new notification.

Given that this doesn't seem to be the case, the workaround is to call scheduleLocalNotification if your application logic requires that notifications that are scheduled in the past need to be presented to the user.

```
UILocalNotification *ln = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[ln setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-2]]; // two seconds ago
// ...

// the following line works as expected - the notification fires immediately
[application scheduleLocalNotification:ln];  // Using this line works as expected

// using the following does NOT work as expected - the notification does not fire
//application.scheduledLocalNotifications = [NSArray arrayWithObject:ln];
```

(I tested this on the iOS 6 simulator)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I ended up just handling the notification myself since I only post notifications when my app is in the foreground anyway, so if they "fire now" it would just end up calling my app... so I removed the middle-man.  I bet inside the iOS setter function for scheduledLocalNotifications it is just skipping any that have already occured -- still a bug (or docs are wrong) in my opinion.